# Check if checkbox is checked without javascript

Tags: html, forms

I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is even possible, but it's worth a try.

I need to make an html form and put a checkbox there (a "I accept the terms and conditions"). When the user clicks submit, it should verify if the checkbox is checked and display an error message if it isn't. But the trick is that I'm not allowed to use JavaScript, as my client doesn't support it.

What can I do?

EDIT: I'm looking for a client-side solution, if that's not possible, then I'll have to live with it :p

Comment: server side validation then ?

Answer (score 0):

Without javascript you're going to have to rely on something server side to do the validation for you (PHP, CGI script, Python, anything really). Submit your form to this validation URL and return an error if the checkbox is not checked. Without more useful information (your environment for one) I can not provide any examples.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML 5 you can use the 
'Required' attribute for  checkboxes,
Which causes the form not to be submitted unless it is checked
You can read up on it more here:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input